# Windows Media Player Web Interface & Remote Video

Tags: video, video-streaming, media-player

I'm using MPC web interface to control the player through a web page.

calling

```
http://127.0.0.1:13579/browser.html?path=C:\path\to\video.mp4
```

in a browser loads a video in MPC

```
http://127.0.0.1:13579/command.html?wm_command=889
```

plays the video currently loaded

Now my problem is that I want to load a video located on the network, something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:13579/browser.html?path=http://path/to/video.mp4
```

And that doesn't work, I'm just redirected to the browser root

If in MPC I do File>Open File... and type the exact same video address (http://path/to/video.mp4) it is properly loaded and read.

Any idea how to make this work would be welcome

Comment: it seems when you use the UI it simply downloads the file first; perhaps better use a player which does have a support for programmatic network stream playback, such as `vlc`; besides, mpc-hc is abandoned since 2017